# How to split files that utilise Firebase into separate files for Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I have decided to convert my project to use Webpack as it was getting pretty messy and I'm struggling to have multiple js files for each part of the app (member, plan, auth, etc) that uses Firebase in some way (functions, database, auth, etc). It seems evverything needs to be in index.js to work.

I always get a (different) weird error that relates to Firebase not be accessible from the index.js file.

How do I structure this so that I can use Firebase in multiple files and then bundle into one with Webpack at the end?

Here's what I have:

**index.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics();

const auth = getAuth();

// Javascript
import './js/auth.js';
import './js/members.js';

// Styles
import './scss/fonts.scss';
import './scss/auth.scss';
import './scss/main.scss';
import './scss/navbar.scss';
import './scss/buttons.scss';
import './scss/inputs.scss';
...
```

**members.js**

```
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions();
const listMembers = httpsCallable(functions, 'listMembers');
listMembers()
  .then((result) => {
    const data = result.data;
    const sanitizedMessage = data.text;
    console.log(sanitizedMessage);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const code = error.code;
    const message = error.message;
    const details = error.details;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this way in my project with multiple js file sharing one database:

1. export `db` in **index.js**, like this:

```js
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

2. import `db` in other JS file e.g. in your **members.js**, you can write:

```js
import {db} from './index.js'   //make sure the file path is right for you
```